# PS Get/Set-ADGroup issues accepting variable/object input

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server, distribution-list

I'm creating Distribution Lists, and trying to populate the AD Description field. Set-ADGroup appears to be the correct cmdlet for this task, however I'm having trouble using it inside a simple script, or using a variable to pass along the required parameters or objects.

This works:

```
Get-ADGroup -Identity "CN=My Group Name,OU=Distribution,OU=Groups,DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=tld"
```

But this doesn't:

```
$GroupDn = Get-Group -Identity "My Group Name" | Select-Object DistinguishedName
Get-ADGroup -Identity $GroupDn
```

And fails with this error:

> get-adgroup : Cannot find an object with identity: '$GroupDn' under:
>   'DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=tld'. At line:1 char:1
>   + get-adgroup -Identity '$GroupDn'
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ($GroupDn:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroup], ADIdentityNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroup

$GroupDn is storing this object:

```
PS D:\Scripts> $groupdn

DistinguishedName
-----------------
CN=My Group Name,OU=Distribution,OU=Groups,DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=tld
```

I assumed this is because Get-ADGroup is expecting string input, but I also know this is Powershell and objects and all that is the magic, the secret sauce, but my roux appears to be lumpy and I'm missing some key point.

So, is string input what I should be handling here? If so, what's the *right* way to get that DN into a string?

Or what part of the object secret sauce am I missing?

Comment: Try piping the object to your get command: `$groupDn | Get-ADGroup`

Comment: Or feed the DN directly into the `identity` parameter: `get-adgroup -identity $groupdn.distinguishedname`

Comment: The reason you are having trouble is because when you pipe to `Select-Object`, you are outputting a `PSObject` instead of an `ADGroup` object. The -identity parameter either needs a direct value that it recognizes as an `ADGroup` property value or an `ADGroup` object itself.

Comment: Running `$groupdn.distinguishedname` returns nothing and when I use that in the `-Identity` parameter it tells me "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. the Argument is null."

Comment: @AdminOfThings I surmised that was the case. Object /= object. I'll do some more research on getting the correct type of object. I feel that's a key thing in PS, and grasping it would make me a lot better at PS in general.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I've attempted that as well and got no luck.

Comment: Just in case it isn't a typo, but your `$GroupDN` assignment uses `Get-Group` instead of `Get-ADGroup`.

Comment: Also, unless you have edited the error message, you should not see `$GroupDN` in the first line of the exception message. It should be the expanded if it contains a string or interpreted as empty or null. It makes it appear that you have used the command `Get-ADGroup -identity '$GroupDN'`. Using single quotes around the variable makes it a literal string and it will not be evaluated. You do not need quotes around the variable.

Comment: I did not edit the error. I have anonymized the content including the group name and DN path. Everything else is an exact transcription.

Comment: Try with `$GroupDn = Get-ADGroup -Identity "My Group Name" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName`, so `$GroupDN` will contain just the DistinghuishedName of the group as **string**, not an object with a property called `DistinghuishedName`. Or do what @TheIncorrigible1 commented and pipe the **object** through to the `Get-ADGroup` cmdlet and leave out the `-Identity` parameter.

Comment: Looks like both those methods work @Theo, and thank you for helping me past the thing I was missing. I was able to successfully use `$GroupDn = Get-Group...` to store the entire object. Basically, the lines I was using but dropping the `Select-Object` bit. And what you offered is what I was looking for as a store-just-the-string option. Thank you. If you'd like to write up an answer I'd be happy to accept.

Comment: What about adding `-Server subdomain.domain.tld` to your second `Get-ADGroup` command? I just happen to notice that you mentioned a subdomain. Not sure of what your AD structure is and what domain your computer is on, but we have a couple child domains and I find that if I add that parameter, it helps.

Comment: @Joseph I'm actually already doing that were applicable. The problem appears to be that the Exchange server I'm creating the DL on is not an AD server, or something similar. I'm not at my computer right now to confirm the error. Basically, while I can run the Exchange based cmdlets OK using that parameter, I cannot run `get-aduser` in this script that way against the same server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested.

The problem with your code is that it gets the distinghuished name as **PSCustomObject** with a property called 'DistinghuishedName', where you really want to get this property as **String**.

If you change that to (using Exchange `Get-Group`):

```
$GroupDn = Get-Group -Identity "My Group Name" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
```

or (using ActiveDirectory `Get-ADGroup`):

```
$GroupDn = Get-ADGroup -Identity "My Group Name" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
```

The variable `$GroupDn` will then contain just the DistinghuishedName of the group as string that can be used as `-Identity` parameter for other AD commands.

`Get-ADGroup` can also be used in another type of syntax, namely by passing an *object* through the pipeline. This object needs to have at least one of these properties: `DistinguishedName`, `GUID`, `SID` or `SamAccountName`.

```
$GroupObject = Get-Group -Identity "My Group Name"
$GroupObject | Get-ADGroup
```

Using this syntax, you do not need to set the `Identity` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I was also able to pipe like this:

```
Get-Group | % { Get-ADGroup -Identity $_.DistinguishedName }
```

It still seems not to play well with different domains though, but this would definitely work for groups in the same domain. The key as to why something like `Get-Group | Select DistinguishedName` or `Get-Group | Get-ADGroup` doesn't work is to use the `Get-Member` cmdlet. So running something like:

```
Get-Group | Get-Member
Get-Group | Select DistinguishedName | Get-Member
```

Should return something like this:

```
TypeName: Deserialized.Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Management.WindowsGroup
TypeName: Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
```

And as you can see from there, that is not what would be accepted from a pipeline into the `Get-ADGroup` cmdlet.

Comment: The groups are in the same domain, but there is a cluster of Exchange servers, and sync between them is not instantaneous, hence needing to specify the server argument.